# Parsing through an XML file using a randomly generated integer

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

This has absolutely stumped me. I have an XML file which is basically a list of items that my program will be using in the game, each item has an associated ID such as

```
<Items>
<Item ID ="1">
  <Name>Food</Name>
  <Price>1 copper</Price>
 </Item>
</Items>
```

How can I write my code so that I can parse through the XML using that random integer? Once I find the correct ID for that integer then I will get the elements from the XML file and my game will then use them.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Linq to Xml you can select item element which have ID attribute equal value to your integer `id` variable:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
var item= xdoc.Descendants("Item")
              .FirstOrDefault(i => (int)i.Attribute("ID") == id);
```

Now if element with specified ID exists (i.e. item not null) you can write all it's elements value to `Dictionary<string, string>` with element name as key and element value as value:

```
if (item != null)   
{
    settings = item.Elements()
                   .ToDictionary(e => e.Name.LocalName, e => (string)e);   
}
```

Usage of settings dictionary:

```
if (settings.ContainsKey("Name"))
    name = settings["Name"]; // if id == 1 then name will be "Food"
```

Comment: This has to do with multiple elements though, I can't have a static Element since each ID has different elements to it.

Comment: @Miguel what do you mean by multiple elements? Id is not static here

Comment: I mean as in the "Name = (string)i.Element("Food"),
               Price = (string)i.Element("Price")"

Comment: Other ID's are going to have other associated elements to it, so if Its ID 2, the elements are going to be something else, a name might be dagger for example and the price would be 5 copper. Unless I'm completely going braindead and not understanding properly, which may very well be the case.

Comment: @Miguel you haven't specified that in question

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: I think the confusion is in your code where you have "Food" as the element name. I think you want to change that to "Name". (i.e. `i.Element("Name")`)

Comment: @JimMischel yep, you are right. But after last OP comment that code was not solving problem. Now I just read all elements into `Dictionary<string, string>`

Comment: Yeah, sorry about all the confusion. Haven't had my coffee yet.

Comment: @Miguel OK, now adding explanations for others :) Please next time provide some code you already have - we will help you to solve problems

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Will do.